# modal window isn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a Bootstrap website and I want a modal window to pop up when users click on the login/register link but I think there is something wrong with the code because even the link isn't responding. here is the code below.

Each time I click on any of the links the modal appears in a funny way, I even tried to include it from a different file but the link isn't responding too

```
       <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Heart2Heart</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />



  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slippry.css">
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/color/default.css">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.techie.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script></head>
<body>
<header>

<div id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Heart2Heart</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"><nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#works">How It Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#testimonial">Testimonial/Referees</a></li>
        <li><a href="#privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>


        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>


        <li><a href ="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">Login/Register</a></li>


      </ul></nav>
         <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Do you want to close this dialog?</p>
            <p class="text-warning">
              <small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->



    </div>

  </div>
</div>



</header>




<!-- section intro -->
<section id="intro">
            <ul id="slippry-slider">
              <li>
                <a href="#slide1"><img src="assets/img/slide/1.jpg" alt="Welcome to Groovin!"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#slide2"><img src="assets/img/slide/2.jpg"  alt="This is an awesome bootstrap template"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#slide3"><img src="assets/img/slide/3.jpg" alt="Check it out, you are going to <span class='red'>♥</span> it :)"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
</section>
<!-- end intro -->
<!-- Section about -->
<section id="about" class="section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3><span>About us</span></h3>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <section id="feature">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="wrap-item text-center">
              <div class="item-img">
                <img src="assets/img/ser01.png">              </div>
              <h3 class="pad-bt15">Financial Freedom</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="wrap-item text-center">
              <div class="item-img">
                <img src="assets/img/ser02.png">              </div>
              <h3 class="pad-bt15">Online Support</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="wrap-item text-center">
              <div class="item-img">
                <img src="assets/img/ser03.png">              </div>
              <h3 class="pad-bt15">40% On ROI</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="wrap-item text-center">
              <div class="item-img">
                <img src="assets/img/ser04.png">              </div>
              <h3 class="pad-bt15">Secured Platform</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="sub-heading">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ultricies libero id augue vulputate mattis. Nunc id interdum libero, ut pulvinar metus. Etiam commodo elit elit, sed pharetra turpis porta at. Fusce quis consequat ipsum. Aenean hendrerit pretium velit, vel aliquam arcu sollicitudin eu. Nullam sit amet lorem et ligula condimentum convallis id eget nisi. Duis lacinia porttitor commodo. Vivamus nec sem vel purus rhoncus sodales. Mauris ante quam, efficitur et sapien vel, eleifend ultricies massa. Praesent pretium vulputate nisi. Ut ac imperdiet lacus. Donec non sollicitudin ligula. Donec tortor nisi, tincidunt lobortis egestas sed, molestie eu elit. Etiam feugiat volutpat libero at dictum. Nunc aliquam tempor ultrices.
                </p>
            </div>



    </div>


</section>
<!-- end section about -->







<!-- section works -->
<section id="works" class="section gray">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3><span>How it works</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-heading">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ex diam, vestibulum nec mauris eget, interdum venenatis mauris. Sed vel dictum lectus. Suspendisse volutpat blandit viverra. Praesent turpis nibh, iaculis et tellus in, dignissim tempus enim. Suspendisse nec massa orci. Pellentesque eu leo sagittis, bibendum ligula at, dignissim leo. Donec facilisis eget metus vel maximus. Sed sit amet interdum augue. Donec finibus, arcu non tempus sagittis, lectus dui auctor lectus, placerat egestas eros tellus venenatis lacus. Nulla fringilla turpis eget erat imperdiet, sed dictum dolor imperdiet. Etiam sollicitudin lectus non feugiat vehicula.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="grid effect" id="grid">
                        <li>
                            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="assets/img/portfolio/1.jpg">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>                        
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/2.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/3.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/4.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/5.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/5.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/6.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/6.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/7.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/7.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/8.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/8.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/9.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/9.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/10.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/10.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>  
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/11.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/11.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/12.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/12.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/13.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/13.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/14.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/14.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>   
                        </ul>
        </div>
    </div> -->
</div>
</section>



<section id="testimonial">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3><span>Testimonials</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-heading">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ex diam, vestibulum nec mauris eget, interdum venenatis mauris. Sed vel dictum lectus. Suspendisse volutpat blandit viverra. Praesent turpis nibh, iaculis et tellus in, dignissim tempus enim. Suspendisse nec massa orci. Pellentesque eu leo sagittis, bibendum ligula at, dignissim leo. Donec facilisis eget metus vel maximus. Sed sit amet interdum augue. Donec finibus, arcu non tempus sagittis, lectus dui auctor lectus, placerat egestas eros tellus venenatis lacus. Nulla fringilla turpis eget erat imperdiet, sed dictum dolor imperdiet. Etiam sollicitudin lectus non feugiat vehicula.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3><span>Referal Links</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-heading">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ex diam, vestibulum nec mauris eget, interdum venenatis mauris. Sed vel dictum lectus. Suspendisse volutpat blandit viverra. Praesent turpis nibh, iaculis et tellus in, dignissim tempus enim. Suspendisse nec massa orci. Pellentesque eu leo sagittis, bibendum ligula at, dignissim leo. Donec facilisis eget metus vel maximus. Sed sit amet interdum augue. Donec finibus, arcu non tempus sagittis, lectus dui auctor lectus, placerat egestas eros tellus venenatis lacus. Nulla fringilla turpis eget erat imperdiet, sed dictum dolor imperdiet. Etiam sollicitudin lectus non feugiat vehicula.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <!---<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="grid effect" id="grid">
                        <li>
                            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="assets/img/portfolio/1.jpg">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="" />
                            </a>                        
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/2.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/3.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/4.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/5.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/5.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/6.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/6.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/7.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/7.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/8.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/8.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/9.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/9.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/10.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/10.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>  
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/11.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/11.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/12.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/12.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/13.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/13.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/img/portfolio/14.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/14.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>   
                        </ul>
        </div>
    </div> -->
</div>
</section>



<section id="privacy" class="section gray">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3><span>Privacy Policy</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-heading">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ex diam, vestibulum nec mauris eget, interdum venenatis mauris. Sed vel dictum lectus. Suspendisse volutpat blandit viverra. Praesent turpis nibh, iaculis et tellus in, dignissim tempus enim. Suspendisse nec massa orci. Pellentesque eu leo sagittis, bibendum ligula at, dignissim leo. Donec facilisis eget metus vel maximus. Sed sit amet interdum augue. Donec finibus, arcu non tempus sagittis, lectus dui auctor lectus, placerat egestas eros tellus venenatis lacus. Nulla fringilla turpis eget erat imperdiet, sed dictum dolor imperdiet. Etiam sollicitudin lectus non feugiat vehicula.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</section>





<!-- section works -->
<!-- section contact -->
<section id="contact" class="section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3><span>Get in touch</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-heading">
                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mutat paulo simul per no, assum fastidii vituperata eam no.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">


    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>We are always online</h4>
                        <p>
            Don't hesitate to get in touch!
            </p>
                        <!-- map -->
                        <div id="section-map" class="clearfix">

                            <img src="assets/img/dummies/Online-Ad-Management.gif">
                        </div>  
        </div>




        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4><i class="icon-envelope"></i><strong>Contact form</strong></h4>

            <!-- start contact form -->
            <div class="cform" id="contact-form">


                <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                <div id="errormessage"></div>
                <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-theme">Send Message</button></div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- END contact form -->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- end section contact -->




<footer>
<div class="verybottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="aligncenter">
                <ul class="social-network social-circle">
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoRss" title="Rss"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoLinkedin" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                </ul>   
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="aligncenter">
                    <p>
                         &copy; Heart2Heart - All right reserved
                    </p>
                    <div class="credits">

<!-- javascript -->

  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/slippry.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/nagging-menu.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="assets/js/AnimOnScroll.js"></script>
    <script>
        new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
            minDuration : 0.4,
            maxDuration : 0.7,
            viewportFactor : 0.2
        } );
    </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#slippry-slider').slippry(
        defaults = {
            transition: 'vertical',
            useCSS: true,
            speed: 5000,
            pause: 3000,
            initSingle: false,
            auto: true,
            preload: 'visible',
            pager: false,       
        } 

      )
    });
</script>

<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/typeahead.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2 based on comment:**

**If you are unable to clean up/manipulate assets**: Try simply adding this to your CSS (the `!important`s are to avoid any possible inline styles override):

```
div#myModal.modal.fade {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  display: none !important;
}

div#myModal.modal.fade.in {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

div.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

- Your modal has the following inline styles which are causing it to appear overlayed (not sure what's assigning that to it): `style="opacity: 0.33; display: block;"` (try removing them from your web inspector to see it go away).
- You are loading bootstrap files twice, locally & via CDN (both CSS & JS files), in addition to this, you are loading bootstrap theme and also bootstrap techie CSS, also jquery three times, all these together could be causing conflicts.
- Ideally you would load `bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap.theme.min`, `bootstrap.techie` CSS & your custom CSS file inside of `<head></head>` and `jquery.min`, `bootstrap.min.js` and the rest of the scripts before your `</body>` tag, just once in that order.
- Place your modal right before your closing `</body>` tag, currently it's located inside of your `<footer></footer>` element.

---

**Original Answer:**

- You are missing `data-target="#myModal"` on your modal trigger navbar option, would be: `<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login/Register</a></li>`
- Another issue is, you are placing the modal inside of your navbar
  which is positioned as fixed. Place it outside of any positioned
  element, a good place would be at the end before the closing `</body>`
  tag.

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5mfvj9v2/25/)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help.. i did all you advised me to do, but when include all the  styles and reference links what happens is that after clicking on the login/register link it works perfectly (the modal window pops up), but when i click on another link the modal windows still pops up like an overlay in the background and nothing works anymore.. please what can i do to resolve this.

Comment: The overlay in the background is typical of the modal being inside a fixed or relative positioned parent container. Could you share a screenshot? Also note that it's worthless to include all your local assets in the question since they can't be loaded anyways, also reducing the code to a minimal working example greatly helps to isolate the issue instead of pasting everything.

Comment: how do i include my screenshot, it would also be nice if i could send you the entire code to help me structure it.. i know i am either not placing the modal in the right place or i am having some js conflict. i tried implementing it somewhere else and i worked.. but i want it on this design.

Comment: @eugbana, I updated the fiddle link in the original answer above to include all your shared code as is, hope helps!

Comment: please take a look at this http://steppingstone.eoilimited.com, i copied and pasted the code but yet i still get the same out put

Comment: @eugbana, edited above with a simpler solution to try, with those CSS tweaks seems to work fine on my end.